# Color selector won't take normal color for my button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to programmatically add selector for background color of my button.

And the problem is: my selector won't take color for normal state and except of that color just put a gray color for background. Note that when I use phone devices with api 16 the problem occurs.

I haven't test it on all apis. And I don't know of it works or not. And note that my code works if I change the normal color (photoshopColor) to a different color.

Here is my selector: ph_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@color/photoshopHoveredColor" android:state_focused="true"></item>
     <item android:drawable="@color/photoshopHoveredColor" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
     <item android:drawable="@color/photoshopColor"></item>
</selector>
```

here is my code:

```
 final Button button = new Button(this);
       button.setTypeface(toolbarFont);
       button.setText(kind);
       button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ph_button);
```

and it is photoshopColor and photoshopHoveredColor that is in my colors.xml inside values folder :

```
<color name="photoshopColor">#00a3e5</color>
<color name="photoshopHoveredColor">#26478e</color>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector to this because you are assigning color in drawable instead of drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/photoshopHoveredColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

<item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/photoshopHoveredColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/photoshopColor" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```